# Need to put a Hyperlink in the Google Script , but it shows error Unexpected Identifier where <a> tag is used

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function sendEmail(fullName, email, newStage) {
  var firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0]
  var URL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/selfschedsstoken=UUsweS1BdS0zOFBXfGRlZmF1bHR8YjJhNmFkNTEwOWFlODZhODRiNGZhYjk4ZjE0N2EwOGY"
  switch (newStage) {
    case "Stage 1": 
     var email_subject= "Update ";
     var email_HTMLbody = "Hey " + firstName + "\n \nThank you for applying ! Upon reviewing your application, we would like to invite you to move forward with our interview process."+ "\n \nThe next step is to schedule a phone call with one of our mentors. The information we need from you can be found broken down below:" + "\n \n1).Please pick an interview time within the next two weeks that work for you. A link to our interview slots can be found <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/selfsched?sstoken=UUsweS1BdS0zOFBXfGRlZmF1bHR8YjJhNmFkNTEwOWFlODZhODRiNGZhYjk4ZjE0N2EwOGY">here </a>
     +"\n \n2).Before your interview, an email will be sent out with a link to Google Meet for you to join 10 minutes prior. These links will be sent to the email you mentioned in your application form." ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     MailApp.sendEmail({
       to: email, 
       subject: email_subject,
       htmlBody: email_HTMLbody
     });
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getting an unexpected identifier because of the double quotes (`"`) in the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

Because you are using double quotes (`"`) to create your string, when you try to use them in the `<a>`, they are ending your string literal.

You currently have:

```
var email_HTMLbody = "Hey " + firstName + "a lot of text... then <a href="someurl
                                                                         ^     ^
                                                            end of string|     |
                                                             this is unexpected|
```

You could escape the double quotes in the `href` with a backslash before the double quote (`\"`):

```js
var email_HTMLbody = "... <a href=\"someurl\">click me </a>"
```

or use backticks:

```js
var email_HTMLbody = `... <a href="someurl">click me </a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, but the result I tried with the same code

It worked when \ n was put in 
 and the URL part of http was enclosed in single quotes.